# Calculating acceleration increase

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

```
^
|
|
|
|                   +
|                  +|
|                +  |
|              +    |
|            +      |
|          +        |
|        +          |
|      +            |
|    +              |
|  +                |
|+                  |
+----------------------------->
o                  x1
```

(X axis is distance and Y is acceleration)

Excuse my crappy ASCII graph but I can't post images so please imagine that the line made of + is actually a concave curve

My question is: knowing x1 how would I calculate the acceleration increase needed to get from O to x1 without overpassing x1?

Comment: It'll help if you could post a fuller explanation, as well as explain more clearly what your problem is, currently the question is very confusing. What kind of a system are you talking about? One can go between two points in space at a constant velocity, without any acceleration as well. Also, what does "overpassing" mean here?

Comment: It's a cartesian coordinate system. I know how to do a constant velocity but it's not what I need. By overpassing I mean going past the value of x1 ( for example when it reaches 1 unit before x1 and the acceleration is > 1 it would pass it)

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop at x1? Or reach a particular acceleration at the same time you reach x1?

Comment: If you have a clearer image please give a link to it and someone with the rep. can edit it into your post.

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164022). Please can you add more detail about the broader picture? That is, why do you want **this** question answered? What will you do with the solution? If you can answer that, we'll be able to give you better answers.

Comment: I want to use this to move a sprite (which is at x1) in my application on 1 axis until it gets to a point x2 with acceleration but I need a formula for the acceleration so that the sprite doesn't go past x2. I only know x1, x2, initial accceleration and speed = 0. Not sure how much clearer I can make this

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem depending on your requirements. Do you know the velocity at x1 and x2? Do you have to get from x1 to x2 in a certain amount of time? Do you need to stop at x2? Do you need *realistic physics*? - If it's a game or something you could maybe get away with just moving at a uniform velocity and stopping on a dime.

Comment: @user1233963: You could e.g. define initial and final state (position?, velocity?, time?) of the point particle; allowed accelerations (only constant jerk?); criteria for optimal solution (fastest time?; less fuel consumption?; [the double integrator](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19720/2451)?), etc, etc.

Comment: I managed to come up with this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum+i%3D0+to+10+%28integrate+from+1+to+10+%28x%2Bi%29%29%29 ,the end of the curve seems about right. Any way to get the start of the curve to begin from a specific point on X ?

Comment: @MichaelBrown: the velocity at x1 is 0 because that's the starting point, I don't know the velocity at x2. There's no time limit. Yes, I need to stop EXACTLY at x2. It doesn't have to be very realistic. I can't get away with moving at a uniform velocity because this is a slidebar, so moving uniformly would look weird.

Comment: If you need to stop at x2 that means you do know the velocity at x2 has to be zero. :) Well then in your case the simplest solution is to pick any acceleration $a(x)$ you want until you get to the half way point $x = (x_1 + x_2)/2$, then exactly reverse that, accelerating at $-a(x_2 - x + x_1)$ until you reach a stop at $x_2$. You are guaranteed to come to a stop (if your numerical accuracy is good enough) since the acceleration profile is symmetric about the midpoint.

Comment: A simple function with the requisite behaviour is $a(x) = A \left(\frac{x_1 + x_2 - 2x}{x_2 - x_1}\right)$ where $A>0$ is the maximum acceleration. There are many other solutions which fit the bill as well.

Comment: See my answer below for more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution is based on the following interpretation of the OP's question (see the comments beneath the question):

Give a function $a(x)$ such that $a(x)$ is the acceleration of a particle at $x$:

$$ \ddot{x} = a(x) $$

and the motion is subject to the following boundary conditions:

$$ \begin{array}{lcl}
x(0) &=& x_1 \\
\dot{x}(0) &=& 0 \\
x(T) &=& x_2 \\
\dot{x}(T) &=& 0
\end{array}
$$

where the final time $T$ is unspecified and we take $x_2 > x_1$ for simplicity.

This is an ill-posed problem in the mathematical sense in that there are clearly many solutions. Any function $a(x)$ which obeys the condition

$$ a(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2} - x) = -a(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2} + x) $$

will satisfy the final constraint by symmetry.

A simple solution is

$$ a(x) = A \frac{x_1 + x_2 - 2 x}{x_2 - x_1} $$

for $A>0$. Integrating the equation of motion subject to the initial conditions gives

$$ x(t) = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2} \cos\left( \omega t \right) $$

where

$$ \omega \equiv \sqrt{\frac{2 A}{x_2 - x_1}} $$

The final time $T$, originally unspecified, can be found from the final condition $x(T)=x_2$:

$$ T = \frac{\pi}{\omega} = \pi \sqrt{\frac{x_2 - x_1}{2 A}}$$

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! 1 question though: who is A exactly?

Comment: $A$ is the maximum acceleration. You can choose it to be whatever you want and it affects the transit time according to the last equation.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the initial velocity and final velocity then you can calculate the acceleration from the $O$ to $X_1$.

$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$

$v = $ velocity at point $X_1$
$u = $ velocity at point $O$
$s = $ distance traveled (which is $X_1$ units)
$a = $ acceleration of the point from $O$ to $X_1$

Here $a$ is nothing but the increment in the acceleration.