# What trajectory minimizes the time traveling between two points under constant acceleration given initial and final position and velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optimization

I have asked this question in the math SE but no one there knew an answer; there are similar questions here but they differ a bit from what I am trying to understand.

I was wondering if there is an (analytical) solution to the problem (in 2D) where the position $\vec{r}_i = \vec{r}(t=t_i)$, $\vec{r}_f = \vec{r}(t=t_f)$ and the velocities $\vec{v}_i = \vec{v}(t=t_i)$, $\vec{v}_f = \vec{v}(t=t_f)$ as well as the constant magnitude of acceleration $|a|$ are given and the goal is to find the vector $\vec{a}(t)/|a| = \vec{e}_a(t)$ that minimizes the time need to transition from the initial state to the final state assuming there are no other forces present.

There is [this](http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/pubs/PiZoWe2008/PiZoWe2008.pdf) paper I found that explains the solution based on it's geometric properties. On page 5 there is a graph that shows that the acceleration is a semicircle rotated and offset from the center with the radius $|a|$ but I don't understand exactly how to compute the actual values for a given initial and final state.

[image: Source is the paper mentioned above.]

I know about Lagrangian multipliers and after reading the Wikipedia page I understand the shooting method but I don't know much about optimal control boundary value problems in general so and extended answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19720/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I do not have the proof that it is optimal, but I suspect it is, but I asked a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922158/in-which-direction-to-accelerate-to-pass-through-the-origin) assuming the direction and magnitude of acceleration would remain constant. This results into solving a quartic equation (forth order polynomial).

Comment: That seems like an interesting post but as far as I understand it the goal seems to be to find the acceleration direction to just pass through the origin, I am interested in matching the final velocity as well!

Comment: Are you asking for an analytical solution (ie a formula)? Or a numerical method of solution?

Comment: A numerical solution is fine too. In a way a numerical solution is described in the paper I linked, I just don't understand how to actually solve it.